# Puppet or Chef to configure webapplication

Tags: deployment, web-applications, puppet, chef

I'm looking for a deployment tool for java based webapps deployment to QA/preprod enviroments. 
Application is typical webapp, compiled to war/ear with .properties file. During deployment (Jboss,tomcat or webshpere) some of properties inside war/ear needs to be configured with different names (like different database host/ports/schemas);
Looked through google for something what could help. Find out that Puppet/Chef is used actively in opensource, but couldn't find any info about possibility to use it as a "war/ear" deployment tool, or I'm totally mistaken.

Answer (score 5):

Puppet & Chef aren't really deployment tools.   You could certainly juryrig something, but they're more config management.   The popular tool these days for what you're doing is called "fabric".  Although others like func or capistrano would work as well.